# How can i get Shipping Rates On Button Click in Magento to instead of Postcode change function

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, shipping-rates

I want to calculate Shipping Rates on button click instead of postal code change.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking this file :

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rate-service.js

There is the code :

```
quote.shippingAddress.subscribe(function () {
        var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();

        if (processors[type]) {
            processors[type].getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
        } else {
            processors.default.getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
        }
    });
```

Which getting the shipping rates.
So you need to do the custom code on your button click, so it will call one function of js and from that js function you can call this code.